# Device RADIO firmware version number in android 1.6

Tags: android

how can i get radio firmware version number in API level 4.

Answer (score 1):

It's only avaliable for Froyo onwards.

> API level 8 or Android 2.2

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by reading `gsm.version.baseband` system property (through the `SystemProperties` using the reflection or via `getprop gsm.version.baseband` command). Check [my answer in other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22384448/648313) for the details.