# NoSuchMethodException loading Build.getRadioVersion() using reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm trying to load the radio version of the Android device using reflection. I need to do this because my SDK supports back to API 7, but Build.RADIO was added in API 8, and Build.getRadioVersion() was added in API 14.

```
// This line executes fine, but is deprecated in API 14
String radioVersion = Build.RADIO;

// This line executes fine, but is deprecated in API 14
String radioVersion = (String) Build.class.getField("RADIO").get(null);

// This line executes fine.
String radioVersion = Build.getRadioVersion();

// This line throws a MethodNotFoundException.
Method method = Build.class.getMethod("getRadioVersion", String.class);
// The rest of the attempt to call getRadioVersion().
String radioVersion = method.invoke(null).toString();
```

I'm probably doing something wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
try {
    Method getRadioVersion = Build.class.getMethod("getRadioVersion");
    if (getRadioVersion != null) {
        try {
            String version = (String) getRadioVersion.invoke(Build.class);
            // Add your implementation here
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "getMethod returned null");
    }
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I was specifying a String type parameter accidentally. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

What `Build.getRadioVersion()` actually does is return the value of `gsm.version.baseband` system property. Check [Build](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Build.java#497) and [TelephonyProperties](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/TelephonyProperties.java#36) sources:

```
static final String PROPERTY_BASEBAND_VERSION = "gsm.version.baseband";

public static String getRadioVersion() {
    return SystemProperties.get(TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_BASEBAND_VERSION, null);
}
```

According to AndroidXref this property is [available even in API 4](http://androidxref.com/1.6/search?q=&defs=&refs=PROPERTY_BASEBAND_VERSION&project=frameworks). Thus you may get it on any version of Android through `SystemProperties` using the reflection:

```
public static String getRadioVersion() {
  return getSystemProperty("gsm.version.baseband");
}


// reflection helper methods

static String getSystemProperty(String propName) {
  Class<?> clsSystemProperties = tryClassForName("android.os.SystemProperties");
  Method mtdGet = tryGetMethod(clsSystemProperties, "get", String.class);
  return tryInvoke(mtdGet, null, propName);
}

static Class<?> tryClassForName(String className) {
  try {
    return Class.forName(className);
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    return null;
  }
}

static Method tryGetMethod(Class<?> cls, String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
  try {
    return cls.getDeclaredMethod(name, parameterTypes);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}

static <T> T tryInvoke(Method m, Object object, Object... args) {
  try {
    return (T) m.invoke(object, args);
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getTargetException());
  } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```